# fork() not working as expected

Tags: c++, linux, process, fork

I am trying to create a program which spawns two processes -- the first of which monitors the second, and restarts it if it is killed. (The idea is that the only way to kill the second process is to first kill the first.) Below I have code that fails to accomplish my goal.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cerrno>

void makeSiblings();

void run_ping() {

  while (true) {

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    puts("Ping.");
  }
}

void run_monitor(pid_t sibling) {

  while (kill(sibling, 0) != -1 and errno != ESRCH) {

    printf("%d still exists.\n", sibling);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }

  makeSiblings();
}

void makeSiblings() {

  pid_t pid1, pid2;

  if ((pid1 = fork()) == -1) {

    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (pid1 == 0) {

    setsid();
    run_ping();
  }

  if ((pid2 = fork()) == -1) {

    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (pid2 == 0) {

    setsid();
    run_monitor(pid1);
  }
}

int main() {

  makeSiblings();
}
```

When this code is run, it outputs `Ping.` and e.g. `7812 still exists.` every two and one seconds, respectively -- as expected. However, when I from another terminal `kill 7812`, the "Ping" process proliferates to a ridiculous extent -- I appear to be fork-bombing myself, and it's only through spamming `killall` that I'm able to recover.

I appear to have failed to understand some subtlety regarding `fork()`, or perhaps regarding `setsid()`. I would appreciate a pointer or two.

Comment: This is clearly C++, so I removed the 'C' tag.

Comment: It's C++, yes, but the problem is one which should be soluble by a C programmer -- the only reason I wrote it in C++ was to take advantage of the sleep_for() functions. Nevertheless, I defer.

Comment: You should test failure of `setsid`. You should use the debugger. Don't forget to flush streams before `fork`-ing. Try to `strace` your program.

Comment: And the monitor should be the parent process of the monitored program. You cannot forbid a process from being killed with `SIGKILL`

Comment: I think it was a mistake to delete the C tag..

Comment: Basile: Thank you for your advice. This is the first time I have mucked around with processes; I tried to use gdb naively but it didn't go well. I'll research some. With respect to "cannot forbid," is this a technical or an ethical limitation? I am explicitly attempting to prevent the process from being killed by SIGKILL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are fork bombimg... your function calls `fork()` twice, and then both children will eventually call the `makeSiblings()` recursively.

When the first child, the one that calls `run_ping()` finishes, it does not actually finish, but it will call `run_monitor()`. Then it will call  `makeSiblings()` and repeat until it explodes!

The solution is to add an `exit()` call just after `run_ping()`:

```
if (pid1 == 0) {
    setsid();
    run_ping();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // <------ here!
}
```

Also note that you are doing tail-recursion between `makeSiblings()` and `run_monitor()` and that's probably not a good idea, as your stack may overflow.

I would write something like:

```
void run_monitor(pid_t sibling) {
  while (kill(sibling, 0) != -1 and errno != ESRCH) {
      //...
  }
}

void makeSiblings() {
  pid_t pid2 = fork(); //error code ommited

  setsid();
  if (pid2 != 0)
      return;

  //this is now the monitor process
  while (true) {
      pid_t pid1 = fork(); //error code ommited
      if (pid1 == 0) {
        setsid();
        run_ping();
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      }
      run_monitor(pid1);
  }
}
```

But now, instead of `kill(pid, 0)` you would just use `wait()` because the `ping()` process is a child of the monitor one, as it should be.

Comment: good catch! another solution would be to use if-then-else instead

Comment: @malarres: Yes, but I assume that the OP program may be more complicated and have more code in `main()` after `makeSiblings()`. Doing a `return` instead of `exit(0)` may be equivalent in this example, but it will not be so in a more complicated code.

Comment: That's actually not true; I posted all the code I have. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: And I now see what I did wrong. Thank you! Accepting this answer.

Comment: @Arandur: YW. An extra piece of advice. When doing printf-debugging from multi-process applications, prepend the pid of the writing process on every line. It will make things much easier to understand.

Comment: I have noticed the presence of `setsid` on your code. I had a similar problem, and adding it to the child process as you show seems to have solved it. Could you please explain why?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: Well, I only had `setsid` because the OP had it, not that I really needed it, as this issue was unrelated to sessions. My (wild) guess is that you are calling `kill()` with a PID equal to 0, so you are signalling all the processes in your session, and there `setsid` makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In makeSibling function, at the end of the second if block, add an exit(0); or something. Because you are actually fork bombing.
When using fork, you must think about that exit most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

> ... int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);  ... If sig is 0 (the null signal),
>   error checking is performed but no signal is actually sent. The null
>   signal can be used to check the validity of pid. ...

Source: http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill

On one hand, You are actually creating process without killing them.

On the other hand, if the signal you are sending from the other terminal is not killing but only breaking the infinite loop, the first sibling will execute the second fork too.